spring security oauth 2 authorization server social login authorization_request_not_found
my setup is the following:

Spring cloud gateway, oauth2 client
Spring auth server, oauth2 client for 3rd party
Spring resource server, my api
Vue SPA frontend with login page

I want to use the BFF architecture but i have trouble with cookies? redirects? I dont get it anymore.
The flow would look like this:
User → Gateway → Auth-Server
Auth-Server → Google
Google → Auth-Server
Auth-Server → Gateway
Gateway → User
Auth Server:
server:
  port: 9000

logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.security: TRACE

spring:

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/adkit_db
    username: user
    password: password
  sql:
    init:
      mode: always

  security:
    user:
      name: user
      password: password

    oauth2:
      authorizationserver:
        client:
          client-1:
            registration:
              client-id: "client"
              client-secret: "{noop}secret"
              client-authentication-methods:
                - "client_secret_basic"
              authorization-grant-types:
                - "authorization_code"
                - "refresh_token"
                - "client_credentials"
              redirect-uris:
                - "http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/adkit"
              post-logout-redirect-uris:
                - "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
              scopes:
                - "openid"
                - "profile"
                - "email"
            require-authorization-consent: true

      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-id: xya
            client-secret: bza
            scope:
              - openid
              - profile
              - email

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer =
                OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.authorizationServer();

        http
                .securityMatcher(authorizationServerConfigurer.getEndpointsMatcher())
                .with(authorizationServerConfigurer, (authorizationServer) ->
                        authorizationServer
                                .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults())    // Enable OpenID Connect 1.0
                )
                // Redirect to the login page when not authenticated from the
                // authorization endpoint
                .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(
                                new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"),

                                new MediaTypeRequestMatcher(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
                        )
                );

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests -> authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated())
                .oauth2Client(withDefaults())
                .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new FederatedIdentityAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

